# Ways to label Questions that have been ticked as Favorite?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I like to star/favorite questions on StackOverflow that I would like to revisit some time in the future.  Some of them are interesting, some because I'd like to reread when I get home from work.  After a while, these pile up-- there are a lot of them.

My question is, **can we have a feature or way to label these favorites that are essentially bookmarks?**  I'd like to have some that are keepers, with a more permanent label such as *"Interesting"*.  Others, I'd rather label as *"To Read Later"*, *"Funny"*, or *"Good Discussion"*.

This would be at the user level in each of our own accounts.  This would help me organize my bookmarks/favorites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this would be a very good idea. Something like either "favorite folders" or a label system similar to gmail would be really handy.

Common things I would use for labels are:

- Pertaining to work
- Interesting Idea
- Read Later
- Funny
- Pertains to project X

Comment: +1 Yes, exactly what I was thinking, something like Gmail labels!

Answer (score 3):

It would be really nice to have that feature. I'd use it mostly for labeling canonical questions I use for closing other questions as duplicates.