# Enable following questions locked with historical lock

Tags: discussion, feature-request, historical-lock, follow-post

Following questions locked with the historical lock is currently not possible.

Since the historical lock is not set in stone, and it can be removed at any time, there is no reason to prevent following/unfollowing such questions and to be notified if the status of the particular question changes.

Comment: Somewhat related: *[Should locks all have expiration dates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371777/)*

Answer (score -5):

> Since historical lock is not set in stone

This is true by design,

> to be notified if the status of the particular question changes.

but **in practice the *historical lock* is never reversed.** (So this defeats the purpose of following a question with an *historical lock* **to receive activity updates** - because it's unlikely to happen.)

---

**Edit:**

In the comments a few objections were raised

> but this is **good on answers**.

True, although the FR only focused on questions. The *[follow posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661)* feature had a two-fold functionality:

1. Receive activity notifications in the inbox
2. *Following answers* [can't be done using bookmarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1569).

So the argument of following answers on a question that has an historical lock has merit that doesn't depend much on hypothetical  activity but more on the fact there's no other way to *"bookmark answers"* other than following them.

---

My initial argument against this FR was 2-fold

1. Activity on historically locked posts is so unlikely the possibility is almost theoretical.
2. Followed posts [can't be searched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345684) so keeping the list short and manageable seems like the more sensible use case for most users.

Another argument was raised in the comments:

> Similarly having a large list of followed posts **does not seem to be problematic either**.

3. Users with large Q&A portfolios or accounts that get a lot of activity frequently say their inbox has too much activity (and [the notifications can't be muted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298410)), so there is that problem with having a large *follow list*: it will tend to flood your inbox.

And yet another argument that isn't new:

> but some users want **XY**

4. Lastly, some arguments of following inactive Q&As seems to miss the intended functionality that *following* was designed for instead proposing to use it like a variation of *categorizing bookmarks for answers&questions* for which there have been many FRs in the past [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56053), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3912), etc... and well matured debates I won't reproduce here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1617/discussion-on-answer-by-bad-coder-enable-following-questions-locked-with-histori) for archival purposes